# var scope using a while loop

Tags: while-loop, scope

I found a solution for a standard reverse linkedList algo. But its unclear to me why this solution works

```
const reverseList = (head) => {
    let curr = head;
    let prev = null;
    
    while(curr !== null){
        let next = curr.next;
        curr.next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next
    }
    return prev;
};
```

but when I initialize the "next" var outside of the while loop, it times out.

```
const reverseList = (head) => {
    let curr = head;
    let prev = null;
    let next = curr.next;
    while(curr !== null){
        curr.next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next
    }
    return prev;
};
```

My guess is it has something to do with scope, but not sure. Any ideas?

I expected initializing the next var outside of the while loop to work since two other vars are initialized outside the while loop but are used within the while loop as well

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Hint: when does the value of `next ` change?

Comment: Not a matter of scope. But you are never updating `next` in your second code snippet ... So when your list has at least two elements, your second snippet will run into an endless loop. Because `next` will be different from `null` and you are always assigning `curr = next`, thus your condition `curr != null` will always be `false`  ...

Comment: @LeviRamsey While in principle one should always tag the language used (I assume javascript), the issue with OP's code doesn't really depend on the language ...